# UL margin is not working

Tags: css, margin

The margin I'm adding to the middle list uls on this page [here](http://www.inside-guides.co.uk/brentwood/lifestyle/2014/January/win-lunch-for-2-at-smiths-ongar.html) isn't working if any has any ideas:

```
ul {
font-size: 0;
margin: 2em 0;
}

<ul>
 <li>List Item 1</li>
 <li>List Item 2</li>
 <li>List Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Can you make a Fiddle or show a bit of HTML. How would we be able to find it in your website what you are talking about?

Comment: ul with display: block? Container with overflow: auto?

Comment: I know, I'll use jsfiddle in future and add the basic html.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have this another property:

> font-size:0

With that you are almost hidding the display behavior because the margin is setted in `em` units:

- then if `font-size` is = 0 <---> `margin` is = 0.

If you remove that then the `margin` can work. Or you can change the units for the `margin` value too.

Comment: Yep in fact all you need is some value different form 0.

Comment: Actually I meant using a pixel value for the margin, if for some reason the OP doesn't want to remove the `font-size:0`

Comment: aaa ok @lukasgeiter I get the point you are right let me complement the answer.

Comment: Well spotted, thanks. I set the 'font-size: 0' to make the default margins/padding on the lis the same as they can be inconsistent. I'll take it off the uls though or use pixel margins instead.

Comment: @253 Using `font-size: 0` is a terrible hack.  There are other ways to deal with undesired whitespace that are less destructive (see: http://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/).  Also, it doesn't work in Android 2.3 (40% of Android devices are running this version).

Comment: @cimmanon I know it's not great and yeah it's the inline I had issues with - I'll check out the other one, thanks.